# Check is event exist before add new calendar event Android

Tags: android, events, calendar

I want to check if an event exist in a calendar before I add new events:
Here is a code by which I am adding an event:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();              
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
            intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
            intent.putExtra("beginTime", date.getTime());
            intent.putExtra("allDay", true);
            intent.putExtra("rrule", "FREQ=YEARLY;COUNT=1");
            intent.putExtra("endTime", date.getTime()+60*60);
            intent.putExtra("title", "Blub");
            intent.putExtra("description", "Bla Blu Bli");
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

Now please guide me how to check the already existing events in calendar?

Comment: SO, what's the question???

Comment: Is this event exist in calendar?????

Comment: What event? I think you may misunderstand the `Calendar` class. It is a Java class for converting/manipulating `Date` objects.

Comment: I will add events or items or something into Calendar or whatever... but first i will check isEvent.exist() ???? :D

Comment: so what was the solution for this??????